# Roaming data not syncing between devices

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, synchronization, win-universal-app, roaming

I have a Windows 8.1 Universal app (not yet published in store) and I want to be able to sync data between app from a desktop and app from Tablet. Both pc and tablet are on the same Microsoft account.

I have some roaming data and I want to sync them between my devices. The data are saved locally corectly but when I go to the other device I have, and open the app, the data are not synced. Do I need to add anything more than:

```
ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings.Values["somekey"] = "something";
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are looking the app locally, the date is not changing on other device if you change one. Here the data is being saved locally. But when you publish the app in store, roaming data will be saved on Microsoft servers and then change of value at one location will affect the other.

Comment: So you say in order for the app to work is to actually publish the app on store?

Comment: Yes. Because as you are working with app on your system, the RoamingSettings will be saved in your system locally.

Comment: Good luck for your app.